# multiple nginx installation on same server how to set one as default

Tags: nginx, debian, symlink, nginx-location

I'm configuring an nginx server to stream using rtmp.

As I just found out I have different nginx installations.

One is located on /etc/nginx (the old one, and the one that is running by default), and other one it's on /usr/local/nginx.

I want to make a symbolic link somewhere so I can define that the server executes the one located at /usr/local

> Doing some more reading, I realized that I had 2 nginx was because I installed one with apt-get and a newer version from source. I uninstalled with apt-get purge. Now what I need to find out is how to set the nginx installed from source as default system.

The nginx installed from source is up and running, but I can't do a restart by any means.

Comment: Why you want multiple nginx in first place?

Comment: Now you and I know why lol @AlexeyTen

Comment: What's the output of `whereis nginx`?

Comment: "nginx: /usr/local/nginx" but if I run "sudo service nginx restat" it prompts with "nginx: unrecognized service"

Comment: Installing something without apt-get should be last resort. If you need newer version try to use Nginx's PPA

Comment: I know how to uninstall it without apt-get clean, but I don't want to uninstall it, I need the one installed from source, but I can't restart it for example. Even if I try to do it from "/usr/local/nginx/sbin"

Comment: Solved it by using /usr/local/nginx/sbin$ sudo ./nginx -s stop

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin$ sudo ./nginx -s stop
/usr/local/nginx/sbin$ sudo ./nginx
```

Did the trick.